# Connect to shared folder on Windows VM

Tags: windows, vmware, windows-networking

### Setup

VMWare Windows Server 2012

- IP 192.168.101.160
- Running on Linux host, but Networktype 'bridged' (Linux host IP is different)
- Network:

  - Shared folder 'C:\test', shared as '\\MOBIL\test' and visible in Network/MOBIL
  - Other computers: only the host computer is visible with its shared folders, not my Windows 10 laptop
- Runs a HTTP(S) Server on :80 / :443
- Remote Desktop Connection activated
- Connected to WLAN 'my_home'
- Windows user: a random administrator account

My Laptop Windows 10

- Can do RDP to the VM
- Can call http(s)://192.168.101.106
- Network:

  - Can NOT resolve \\192.168.101.106 or \\192.168.101.106\test or \\MOBIL\test
  - "MOBIL" Computer is not listed in network
- Connected to WLAN 'my_home'
- Windows user: my personal account

### Question

How can I reach the 'test' folder on the VM from my Windows 10 machine WITHOUT remote desktop?

(I want to run a script that automatically copies files from my computer to the VM folder. So far I have done that by mapping the network folder to a drive Z:/ and then just copy the files because I cannot get SSH to work with a keyfile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can successfully RDP to the system and hit the IIS service, I would have to assume you're hitting a firewall issue. You'll need to open up the firewall to allow for SMB traffic.